# How to Push the random numbers into the array and sum them using ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, numbers

I have a random number generator method which generates a particular random number b/w 1 - 6.
I pushed them into the array one by one, but the problem is, every time i generate the random number, the current value is pushed only, and not the previous ones.

```
for eg, I generate 2 //[2]
then generate 4 //[4]
then generate 1 //[1]
then generate 5 //[5] and so on.
```

I want the array like this [2, 4, 1, 5, ...]...much like a stack
then i need to sum the numbers inside the array as well. please help!
my code -

```
const [count, setCount] = useState<number | null>(null);

function randomNumberGenerate(min: any, max: any) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};

useEffect(()=> {
setCount(randomNumberGenerate(1, 10))
}, [count]);

let array : any[] = [];
var itemInArray = count; //initially
array.push(itemInArray);
console.log(array);
```

it is pushing the only current count number to the array, whenever i generate a new count.
I want to keep the old generated numbers into the array as well.
//this way - [1, 3, 5, 4, 1, 5, 6, 8, 7, ...] (every time i generate count)
and also want to sum them all.
Any help would highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you have done two mistakes:

- made a `setCount` inside a useEffect and that will trigger infinite component rerender (I don't know if you want to be like this)
- when component rerender the array is set to an empty array.

you must initialize the array outside the component or store it in useState
,create the sum = 0 variable ( the sum variable will increase every random number is generated)

```js
const [count, setCount] = useState<number | null>(null);
const [array, setArray] = useState<[]>([]);
// you can init sum outside the component without using useState
const [sum, setSum] = useState<number>(0);

function randomNumberGenerate(min: any, max: any) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};

useEffect(()=> {
setCount(randomNumberGenerate(1, 10))
setArray([...array, count]);
setSum(sum + count);
console.log(array);
}, [count]);
```

I hope this to be the solution :)

Comment: I have made the setState call inside the useEffect as I want to trigger two setStates at the same time , but useState hooks are asynchronous (and ended up occuring one after the other), but on using useEffect, it made my 2 useState hooks synchronous and thus helped me in updating the 2 states at the same time.